# Subcolumns with multicol and the exam class

Tags: spacing, multicol, exam

I'm using the `multicol` package with the exam class to create 2 sub-columns within a `multicols` environment for checkbox answers when the answers are short and one word. There is a significant amount of whitespace between answers in the sub-columns, however, and `\setlength\columnsep{Xpt}` doesn't seem to bring them closer together.

In the example below, the space between the two columns in the second question needs to be compacted:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{40pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{My Form}]
\begin{questions}
\question Is this a question\hfill
\mbox{
    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Yes
        \choice No
    \end{oneparcheckboxes}
}
\question These columns are too far apart
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{checkboxes}
        \choice Apple
        \choice Banana
        \choice Cucumber
        \choice Eggplant
        \choice Fruit
        \choice Grapes
    \end{checkboxes}
\end{multicols}
\question Comments:\ \hrulefill
\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is missing packages.

Comment: What package(s) is it missing? As far as I know, everything there is supplied by the multicol package or exam class.

Comment: Yes, but you had forgotten to include `multicol`, I added that for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

But changing `columnsep` reduces the spacing (perhaps I am misunderstanding the problem?):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{40pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{My Form}]

\begin{questions}
\question Is this a question\hfill
\mbox{
    \begin{oneparcheckboxes}
        \choice Yes
        \choice No
    \end{oneparcheckboxes}
}
\question These columns are closer now
\setlength\columnsep{-1cm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{checkboxes}
        \choice Apple
        \choice Banana
        \choice Cucumber
        \choice Eggplant
        \choice Fruit
        \choice Grapes
    \end{checkboxes}
\end{multicols}
\question Comments:\ \hrulefill
\end{questions}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked. It was the negative value that seemed to make the difference. 0 or a positive value less than my original columnsep seemed to have little effect.